# Data from .php webpage cannot be imported to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to pull a table(financial data) from the following website into Googlesheets :
https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/relianceindustries/balance-sheetVI/RI#RI

In the webpage there is a "Go"button for converting the data so that it can be pasted into an Excel sheet.
On pressing the Go button and choosing an option (say Profit loss statement-old), the following webpage displays :
https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/company_info/print_main.php
The website says that the data can be copied and pasted into an MS-Excel sheet.
But my query is : How to pull the data in Google Sheets using the IMPORTHTML as I am getting error using
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/company_info/print_main.php","table",2)

Comment: Share you sheet so the respondents cant help you. [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please consolidate the information from your 4 versions of this question here. What is the error? It’s irrelevant to Google docs what is serving the url you put there. This seems unlikely to be on topic for stack overflow, but with more info maybe it is :).